# Change a button's background image programmatically in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

All of the topics that I have searched are outdated or not complete in Obj-c.

I need to learn how to change a button's background image programmatically, when having the actual button in the InterfaceBuilder. (This sounds odd, but I need it for `NSCollectionView` as I have many similar button with different background images).

In the interface builder I drag a button onto my view window, what should I do after?

I understand that:

- I need to create a NSButton Class
- Connect the button from the interface builder to the code
- Set the image

I have been struggling with this.

Comment: please [refer tutorial to create button programatically here](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/8/4/create-a-uibutton-in-code-with-objective-c)

Comment: This tutorial is for the Cocoa Touch and it does not explain the connecting of the button, but rather creating the button from scratch programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So did you connect the button to an IBOutlet property? If so then all you need to do is use [button setImage:]

If you haven't already done so, make sure the object instance that you want to change the image from is in interface builder, I.e has been dropped in as one of those blue boxes. Then if you set the object's class and have an IBOutlet property in the header file you can just drag the button outlet in the outlets tab (looks like an arrow) to the actual button itself to link the two

Edit: So it appears you're having trouble with the actual connecting part of the button? Chances are your IB file looks a bit like this:

[image]

Look for the objects section in the left hand list. These are the actual objects in your code that you can connect your button to. You might see an app delegate object there, which is included in the default IB file generated when you first create a project. If you want to handle the image changing in your app delegate, then simply add this property to your AppDelegate.h file to create an outlet:

```
@property IBOutlet NSButton *button;
```

If you go back to interface builder and select the app delegate object, you can see the outlet that you just created under the outlet tab:

[image]

Drag the little circle thing to the button to connect it, that should be the easiest bit.

But I'm going to just presume that you want to call it from somewhere else other than your app delegate, and for that we'll need to do some more explaining. If the class you want to call it from is a subclass of NSView and *is already in your interface builder*, you can just add that line to your view's header file and it will appear under the view's outlet tab.

If you want to call this from another object that isn't a view or such, you'll need to do either two options:

1. Create the object instance in interface builder. This means that instead of creating in normally with `alloc] init];` etc. you'll have to actually drag in an object into interface builder. This can change the structure of your object quite a bit as you'll no longer be able to create it at will, since it will automatically be instantiated whenever you load your .nib file. Also important to note is that your `init` function will not be called anymore and you'll need to use `awakeFromNib` instead. If you do choose to go down this route, just drag over an object:

[image]

Add your outlet property to the header file:

[image]

Set the object's class:

[image]

And connect the outlet:

[image]

2. If making objects XIB loaded just isn't your thing, you can always just connect the property outlet to your app delegate/view controller and access it from that instead. Hopefully this clears things up, if this was the problem you were having.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luke. Is there anyway I could email you with pictures of what I have done? Its a little bit more complicated than that...

Comment: Why not edit your question to include the screenshots? The more detailed your question you give the better answers you'll get

Comment: I don't like showing my email address publicly, but my profile has a link to my twitter if you'd rather send me links to them there.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I have now created a new topic with some code, perhaps you could look into it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353630/change-background-image-of-a-button-programatically-cocoa-obj-c

Comment: @ShaunArchibald there is no need to create a "foto" property or subclass NSButton, as NSButton already has a background image property which can be edited with `[button setImage:];`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, this explains a lot of the stuff in my NSCollectionView project.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS:

Don't need to create a NSButton subclass.

You only need to add button on Storyboard, set the IBOutlet property for your button (ctr+drag from your button to your view controller), and set the background image with:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

---

For MacOS:

You can use

```
setImage:
```

as describe on [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Tasks/SettingButtonImage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000088-BAJBCGCG), and changes its size/position

(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 1):

ofcourse as Duukee Said,i think no need to create any NSButton Or UIButton Instances Manually When We have an object in Interface Builder,We can just use it's outlet as follows,

```
UIImage* Desired_Image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];
[My_Button setimage:Desired_Image forState:UIcontrolstateNormal];
```

HTH!Happy Coding :)